# jQuery Plugin is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am working on a plugin called "popup" (`$(".messageBox").popup()`).

Here is part of my code:

```
$(this).fadeIn(settings.fadeDuration);
    console.log($(this).attr("class"));

    console.log(settings.timeOut);
    setTimeout( function(){
        console.log($(this).attr("class"));
        $(this).fadeOut(settings.fadeDuration);
}, settings.timeOut);
```

that was the code in `popup.min.js`, now below is the code in `index.html`:

```
$(function(){
    $(".messageBox").popup();
});
```

my popup appears, and fades in correctly, but it doesn't fade out after `1000ms` as it should... what can I do? I opened the console but there is no error shown.

Comment: what is `setting.timeOut` when it writes to the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the `this` reference is wrong inside the `setTimeout` callback method

You can either use a closure variable to hold the reference

```
$(this).fadeIn(settings.fadeDuration);
console.log($(this).attr("class"));

console.log(settings.timeOut);
var el = this;
setTimeout( function(){
    console.log($(el).attr("class"));
    $(el).fadeOut(settings.fadeDuration);
}, settings.timeOut);
```

or use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to pass a custom context to the callback

```
$(this).fadeIn(settings.fadeDuration);
console.log($(this).attr("class"));

console.log(settings.timeOut);
setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("class"));
    $(this).fadeOut(settings.fadeDuration);
}, this), settings.timeOut);
```